# Use counters in a bar chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, counters, nameref, totcount

I have a document consisting of different topics within multi-variable calculus. I want to start the document with a bar chart displaying how many problems there are of each kind, based on the number of problems in the document. In other words I want the bar chart displayed below

[image]

to be automatically generated based on the contents and number of sections in my document. However I ran into a plethora of problems trying to automate this.

- I was unable to place the bar chart at the start of the document because the counters to count the subsections has yet to be been defined. Is it possible to make `totcount` work here?
- I was unable to create the contents of `symbolic y coords` using a `foreach` loop.
- Nameref is not working inside `symbolic y coords`

Any help solving these three problems would be much appreciated.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, norsk, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{nameref}
\newcommand{\seksjon}[1]{\section{#1}\label{sec:\arabic{section}}\newcounter{problem\arabic{section}}}
% Defines a simple bold text, \oppgave[text] produces Oppgave 1 (text). 
\NewDocumentCommand{\oppgave}{o}{%
  % <code>%
  \noindent\\
  % \textbf{\large Oppgave~\stepcounter{problemMA1103}\arabic{problemMA1103}}
  \textbf{\large Oppgave~\stepcounter{problem\arabic{section}}\arabic{problem\arabic{section}}}
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
  {}
  {(#1)}%
  \medskip\\\noindent
  % <code>
}
\usepackage{totcount}
\regtotcounter{section}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\seksjon{Integrals}

\oppgave

\seksjon{Derivatives}

\oppgave
\oppgave
\oppgave
\seksjon{Green's theorem}

\oppgave
\oppgave
\seksjon{Gauss' Theorem}

\oppgave
\oppgave
\seksjon{Stokes Theorem}

\oppgave
\oppgave
\oppgave
\oppgave


The total number of chapters is \total{section}, in \nameref{sec:1} there are
\arabic{problem1} problems and in \nameref{sec:5} there are
\arabic{problem5} problems.

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i in {1,...,\arabic{section}}
  {
    \node at (0, -\i) {\nameref{sec:\i}: \arabic{problem\i}};
  }
\end{tikzpicture} 

\begin{figure}[htbp!]
  \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    y=-0.5cm,
    bar width=0.3cm,
    y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
    axis x line       = none,
    tickwidth         = 0pt,
    enlarge y limits  = 0.2,
    enlarge x limits  = 0.02,
    ytick = data,
    nodes near coords,
    symbolic y coords = {%
      Integrals, 
      Derivatives,
      Green's theorem,
      Gauss' theorem, 
      Stokes theorem}
    ]
    \addplot[fill=black] coordinates {%
      (\arabic{problem1},Integrals)
      (\arabic{problem2},Derivatives)
      (\arabic{problem3},Green's theorem)  
      (\arabic{problem4},Gauss' theorem)  
      (\arabic{problem5},Stokes theorem)};
%    \legend{Topics, Posts}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some easy and some not so easy workarounds. The main one is using `refcount` in order to provide an expandable version of `\nameref`.

The other trick is to typeset the tables and figures only after the counters have been registered, or there would be errors at the first LaTeX run.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,norsk,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{refcount}

\newcommand*{\enameref}[1]{%
  \getrefbykeydefault{#1}{name}{}%
}

\newcommand{\seksjon}[1]{%
  \section{#1}\label{sec:\arabic{section}}%
  \newcounter{problem\arabic{section}}%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\regtotcounter{problem\arabic{section}}}%
  \x
}
% Defines a simple bold text, \oppgave[text] produces Oppgave 1 (text). 
\NewDocumentCommand{\oppgave}{o}{%
  \par\addvspace{\medskipamount}%
  \stepcounter{problem\arabic{section}}%
  \noindent\textbf{\large Oppgave~\arabic{problem\arabic{section}}}
  \IfValueTF{#1}{(#1)}%
  \par\addvspace{\medskipamount}%
}
\usepackage{totcount}
\regtotcounter{section}

\begin{document}

\ifcsname c@problem1@totc\endcsname
The total number of chapters is \total{section}, in \nameref{sec:1} there are
\total{problem1} problems and in \nameref{sec:5} there are
\total{problem5} problems.

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i in {1,...,\number\totvalue{section}}
  {
    \node at (0, -\i) {\nameref{sec:\i}: \number\totvalue{problem\i}};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    y=-0.5cm,
    bar width=0.3cm,
    y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
    axis x line       = none,
    tickwidth         = 0pt,
    enlarge y limits  = 0.2,
    enlarge x limits  = 0.02,
    ytick = data,
    nodes near coords,
    symbolic y coords/.expanded = {
      \enameref{sec:1}, 
      \enameref{sec:2},
      \enameref{sec:3},
      \enameref{sec:4},
      \enameref{sec:5},
    }
  ]
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\addplot[fill=black] coordinates {%
      (\number\totvalue{problem1},\enameref{sec:1})
      (\number\totvalue{problem2},\enameref{sec:2})
      (\number\totvalue{problem3},\enameref{sec:3})  
      (\number\totvalue{problem4},\enameref{sec:4})  
      (\number\totvalue{problem5},\enameref{sec:5})
    };
  }\x
%   \legend{Topics, Posts}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\fi


\seksjon{Integrals}
\oppgave

\seksjon{Derivatives}
\oppgave
\oppgave
\oppgave

\seksjon{Green's theorem}
\oppgave
\oppgave

\seksjon{Gauss' Theorem}
\oppgave
\oppgave

\seksjon{Stokes' Theorem}
\oppgave
\oppgave
\oppgave
\oppgave

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Here's an *unfinished* attempt to solve the problem.
- I would use counters and then store the counter value in a `\command` and then use it inside `pgfplots`.
- **I did not solve it though. The counter values are always zero at the beginning of the document. Maybe one can store is as it is stored in TOC generation (@experts).**

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{myCatACount}[section]
\newcounter{myCatBCount}[section]
\newcounter{myCatCCount}[section]

\begin{document}

\section*{pgfplots}

\newcommand{\myValueA}{\themyCatACount} % \the "CounterName"
\newcommand{\myValueB}{\themyCatBCount}
\newcommand{\myValueC}{\themyCatBCount}

\begin{itemize}
\item \texttt{myValueA:} \myValueA
\item \texttt{myValueB:} \myValueB
\item \texttt{myValueC:} \myValueC
\end{itemize}


\section{Cat A}
    \subsection{Probem A.1}
    \stepcounter{myCatACount}
    \texttt{myCatACount:} \arabic{myCatACount}

    \subsection{Probem A.2}
    \stepcounter{myCatACount}
    \texttt{myCatACount:} \arabic{myCatACount}

    \subsection{Probem A.3}
    \stepcounter{myCatACount}
    \texttt{myCatACount:} \arabic{myCatACount}


\section{Cat B}
    \subsection{Probem B.1}
    \stepcounter{myCatBCount}
    \texttt{myCatBCount:} \arabic{myCatBCount}

    \subsection{Probem B.2}
    \stepcounter{myCatBCount}
    \texttt{myCatBCount:} \arabic{myCatBCount}

\section{Cat C}
    \subsection{Probem C.1}
    \stepcounter{myCatCCount}
    \texttt{myCatCCount:} \arabic{myCatCCount}

    \subsection{Probem C.2}
    \stepcounter{myCatACount}
    \texttt{myCatCCount:} \arabic{myCatCCount}

    \subsection{Probem C.3}
    \stepcounter{myCatCCount}
    \texttt{myCatCCount:} \arabic{myCatCCount}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would recommend you checking out my code a bit closer. I was able to generate the counters on the fly, instead of having to define them explicitly at the beginning. I automated everything in your code that you increment "manually". Though, the problem still stands with how to use totcount, or TOC to access the counters at the start of the document.

Comment: Maybe it helps others or helps to attract better answers :).